# Regex positive look behind for regex reverse matching?

Tags: java, regex

How can I match a string literal then reverse direction then match another string literal above it?

Basically match "match" then look behind and match "here:" then match from "here:" to end of string (to eventually delete)

-- input --

```
Keep this

here:
match test test

this should be deleted
```

-- expected output (after match and delete) --

```
   Keep this
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yE0lJ2)

Comment: Why wouldn't you just match on `here.*match`?

Comment: FYI see the regex debugger for why your regex doesn't return anything (and please include this regex in your question here, not only in an external link). If you wanted to match something, you needed to place the lookbehind *before*: `^(?<=here:\n)match.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make this movement, you only need to find "here:" and to ensure that the string contains "match" after (if it is not the case, the pattern will fail):

```
(?s)here:.*?match.*
```

`(?s)` the dot can match newlines

However, if it is possible, you will probably obtain better performances using `indexOf` method with "match" and "here:", comparing the result and cuting the string at the index of "here:"